# Unable to determine if entity is transient or detached on deletion

Tags: nhibernate

Our schema contains a table with a composite primary key. The entity does not have any version/timestamp columns. The mapping is:

```
mapping.CompositeId().KeyReference(e => e.ParentEntity).KeyProperty(e => e.DTFR);
```

When user clicks Delete button, HTTP request is posted to the server, the server creates new NHibernate session and invokes `session.Delete()`:

```
        using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            foreach (var entity in entities)
                session.Delete(entity);
            return trans.TryCommit();
        }
```

But NHibernate gives a warning:

> Unable to determine if {Entity} with assigned identifier {Entity} is
>   transient or detached; querying the database. Use explicit Save() or
>   Update() in session to prevent this.

and loads the entity from database before deletion of it.

We cannot follow recommendation from the warning and use `Save()` or `Update()` to delete entity.

**How should we rewrite our code to avoid excessive querying of database on deletion?**

Comment: How is the `entities` collection populated?

Comment: `entities` are loaded with an HQL (in other NHibernate session), then serialized to JSON, after that passed to client, deserialized, and in the end returned back to server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because the NH session that you're using to delete the entities doesn't know about/isn't tracking them.

For deletion, there's an overload of the `Delete()` [method](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-deleting) that takes an HQL query. This might be a viable, and arguably more efficient, way to do what you want?

Something like:

```
using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    session.Delete($"FROM EntityTable WHERE Id IN ({entities.Select(e => e.Id})");

    return trans.TryCommit();
 }
```

Comment: As I understand your suggestion is to do not feed NHibernate with entities so it does not doubt if they are transient or detached. But I am not sure that I can generate HQL to delete multiple entities with a composite key. Maybe there is an explicit way to say NHibernate to treat entities as transient or detached?

Comment: Have you looked into using the `unsaved-value` attribute in your mapping? This may help.

Comment: It looks like `UnsavedValue("any")` solves the problem:
`mapping.CompositeId().KeyReference(e => e.ParentEntity).KeyProperty(e => e.DTFR).UnsavedValue("any");`

Comment: Nice work. It's interesting to see the effect as this is an attribute that I rarely bother using.